# Migration of Tomcat database setting to Websphere

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere, websphere-8, application-server

I'd like to migrate my java app, which runs locally on `Tomcat 6` to `Websphere 8.5`. The application is deployed on Websphere without any obstacles, nevertheless it won't connect to a database during the startup. I assume that it's because I have to specify the connection info, as well as I did for `Tomcat`, in the `context.xml` file, placed to my tomcat folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        name="jdbc/mydb" password="somepassword" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@123.456.7.89:1521/mynode" username="myusername" />
</Context>
```

Is my assumption correct? How to pass this information to my `Websphere 8.5 AS`?

Comment: Don't mean to speak carelessly, as I haven't worked with Websphere, but could it be that it needs to be built again, similarly to what Tomcat requires to serve an application?

Comment: Is this on Application Server Liberty, or Traditional application server? (are you deploying through wsadmin/Integrated Solutions Console or using server.xmls).

Comment: @AdrianM. I don't think so...

Comment: @ewhoch it's a standard WebSphere AS and I'm deploying through a webconsole

Comment: So basically you need to create a data source in Websphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to configure a JDBC Provider and Data Source in WebSphere just like is done in the `<Resource>` tag of Tomcat's context.xml.

In WebSphere Traditional 8.5.5.x using the administrative console, this is described [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tdat_ccrtpds.html).

If you were on WebSphere Liberty, this would be done using the server.xml, as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html).